# uwp touchpad interactions to control media

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, gestures, touchpad

in my uwp app on my media element page, I want to handle **touchpad gestures** on the laptop, **mouse wheel** handler for the mouse and touch and **swipe** event on touch screens for my app. so that I can increase/decrease volume of the media with same type of gesture on all devices, 
In official docs I cant see any events to catch swipe or scroll gestures. How can I achieve this? **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

> In official docs I cant see any events to catch swipe or scroll gestures. How can I achieve this?

For catching swipe and scroll, they are belong to manipulation gesture, you should be able use manipulation relative events. More details please check Custom touch interactions of [Touch interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/touch-interactions).

[UIElements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement) contains manipulation events such as [ManipulationStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationStarted),[ManipulationDelta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationDelta),[ManipulationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationCompleted) and so on. Details for how to use depend on your requirements and controls. You can also reference the scenario 5 of [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput).